How do I continuously fetch the last N documents from mongodb?
I can fetch the last 10 documents like this:
collection.find({}).sort({_id:1}).limit(10).toArray();

I am building an express api to continuously fetch the next N. For example, Get request with arg=1 would lead to first 10 docs. Get request with arg=2 would then fetch docs 11-20. How do I do that in mongodb?

Use skip with limit.

What does "continuously" mean in this context?  do you mean like a change stream so you get new changes?
